# How to unquote URL after process after lxml.html

Tags: python, lxml

lxml.html will quote URL. But I need to unquote it after processing.How to unquote URL after processing of lxml.html?

```
import lxml.html as html
mandarin = '<a name="中文"/><a href=中文></a>'
e = html.fromstring(mandarin)
print(html.tostring(e, encoding='unicode'))
```

The Result:

```
<span><a name="%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87"></a><a href="%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87"></a></span>
```

I'm expecting:

```
<span><a name="中文"/><a href="中文"/></span>
```

Comment: What are you going to be doing with it?

Comment: Yes but what are you going to be doing with it exactly?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm processing some files, they have to stay the same after being processed. I'm not going to send a request to a server.

Comment: the unquote should be fine. It will just decode.